# How to get props in child component using v-bind object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to pass all the properties in an object as `props`, and use `v-bind` without an argument.

But how can I get the `props` in the child without having to declare the props in the child component?

For example, in the code below **`item` is an object.**

**Parent component:**

```html
<div v-for="item in domArr" :key="item.id">
  <cus-dom v-bind="item"></cus-dom>
</div>
```

**Child component:**

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'cusDom',
    props: [],   // HOW TO GET THE props, because I have it empty/no arguments HERE?
    data() {
      return {};
    },
    mounted() {
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: oh sorry. I will edit soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when using `v-bind`, you still have to declare them as `props`.

If you don't they will be `$attrs`.

See **demo below**, should make it clear.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['a'],
  template: `<button @click="go">PROPS AND ATTRS</button>`,
  mounted() {
    this.go()
  },
  methods: {
    go() {
      console.log(
      '$attrs:', JSON.stringify(this.$attrs), '- $props:', JSON.stringify(this.$props),
      '- a:', this.a, '- b:', this.b)
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    stuff: {a: 1, b: 2}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <child v-bind="stuff"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Naturally, you can access attributes as `this.$attrs.b`, for instance.

Comment: oh, yes, I got it. Thanks for your help.